# Ember computed alias on array firstObject not working

Tags: ember.js

I have this computed property alias in my component:

```
firstElement: Ember.computed.alias('myArray.firstObject')
```

This works in development, but doesn't update in production mode.

This code though works in both development and production:

```
firstElement: Ember.computed('myArray.[]', function() {
  return this.get('myArray.firstObject');
}
```

Is the alias macro not allowed on firstObject , lastObject, etc..?

It also seems weird that in works in development but not in production mode.

Comment: "Doesn't work" is a little vague, can you be more specific?  Have you set a breakpoint on the computed property function?

Comment: In the alias, initial value is computed correctly but when the array changes, it is not recomputed correctly. It retains the old value

Comment: that is weird; but I can suggest you to use [ember-awesome-macros](https://github.com/kellyselden/ember-awesome-macros); it contains `array.first` and `array.last` macros that can help you.