# Curious behavior when observing Ember's dirtyType property

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I try to observe (in my controller) if my Ember model has changed.

```
personChanged: function() {
    // do stuff
}.observes('person.dirtyType'),
```

This observer is never triggerd unless I will access the `isDirty` property before. For example if I `get` the property in the route (where the model is fetched) the observer is triggerd exactly 1 time.

```
model.people.get('firstObject').get('dirtyType');
controller.set('person', model.people.get('firstObject'));
```

If I want to get the observer triggered every time the model changed I need to access `dirtyType` within the observer again.

```
personChanged: function() {
    this.get('person.dirtyType');
    // do stuff
}.observes('person.dirtyType'),
```

The value of `dirtyType` in the observer is always as expected.

Maybe I'm doing it completely wrong but I can't follow the behavior above.

Answer (score 0):

There is something unpredictable is going on when we use `firstObject` based on this question [Ember computed alias on array firstObject not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44192637/ember-computed-alias-on-array-firstobject-not-working)

I haven't experienced it to confirm. May be until then you can try the below workaround,

```
controller.set('person', model.people.get('firstObject'));
```

Instead of the above, you can define computed property,

```
person:Ember.computed('model.people.[]',function(){
 return return this.get('model.people.firstObject');
})
```

Now your below observer will work all the time.

```
personChanged:Ember.observer('person.dirtyType',function() {
    // do stuff
}),
```

Comment: Unconsumed computed properties do not trigger observers [reference](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.13.0/object-model/observers/#toc_unconsumed-computed-properties-do-not-trigger-observers). so if you are not using `person` inside template then consider `this.get('person')` in init method.

Comment: I was using `person` inside my template but added `this.get('person')` in the init method too. The problem remains.